# Two same message extension installed while setting up a bot in channel

Tags: java, azure, robotframework, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

If I have only "personal" as scope in bot property of manifest, only one app is installed. But, if I add "team", two apps get installed when I set up a bot in channel. It seems both bot and extension is installed and for bot, same extension app is installed. I think that's how I end up with two apps. Is this expected behavior?

Here is my manifest schema:

```js
     "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "<BOT-ID>",
      "scopes": [
        "personal",
        "team"
      ],
      "commandLists": [
        {
          "scopes": [
            "personal"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "logout",
              "description": "log"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "scopes": [
            "team"
          ],
          "commands": [
            {
              "title": "logout",
              "description": "log"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "supportsFiles": false,
      "isNotificationOnly": false
    }
  ],
  "composeExtensions": [
    {
      "botId": "<BOT-ID>",
      "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
      "commands": [
        {
          "id": "searchQuery",
          "type": "query",
          "title": "Search Query",
          "description": "",
          "initialRun": true,
          "fetchTask": false,
          "context": [
            "commandBox",
            "compose"
          ],
          "parameters": [
            {
              "name": "searchQuery",
              "title": "Search Query",
              "description": "",
              "inputType": "text"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
  ]
```

Comment: Could you please provide more details? its not much clear whats exactly happening?

Comment: The main issue is: If I add the bot in teams, two message extension apps are displayed in channel. But, if I add it as a personal app, only one is shown. You can go through this link and check out images. I have added them with description. Link: https://ibb.co/album/jZByzQ

Comment: This might happen due to any duplicate ME existing already. Please delete all the existing ME with similar name from Teams Admin center and check if it helps.

Comment: No, it didn't help. I wasn't able to delete it from admin center, so I deleted the existing apps with similar name from azure registration. After I delete it from azure portal, they no longer appear on admin center. I created an azure bot by following this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-task-modules/7-exercise-use-task-modules-bots
Does it has any missing steps?

Comment: If i try to run any sample from github, I am facing the similar issue. I tried to run this manifest which is very similar to my app manifest, I am getting duplicate apps for this also.
https://github.com/joechiellini-mck/ms-teams-loan-manager/blob/main/src/manifest/manifest.json

Comment: We are able to repro the issue now. If in scope its "personal" it's not showing duplicate ME instance, but if we add the bot in "team" scope, its showing duplicate. We have raised a bug for this issue and engineering team is looking into it. We will inform you once we get further update. Thanks!

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT  Thanks for the update. How much time could it take approximately to get it resolved? We have an app ready to be published to teams. But, I think we would need to wait till this issue gets fixed so that we can test it and then move ahead with publishing.

Comment: There is no specific ETA to share as of now

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I think there are a couple of other bugs also. Could be please verify if these are bugs?

- If I set up a tab in a channel, ME is also installed. I don't think ME should have installed as tab and ME are not related to each other at all.
- Duplicate MEs are installed in team if I set up a tab in a channel. If we handle first point, I think this one automatically gets resolved.

Comment: If you try to set up the app, the app includes all the attributes, so it's expected to add ME as well.

Comment: For Duplicate ME Issue: When you install an app by side loading, it actually creates different app id with existing app due to which it even considers separate app. If you want to get rid of the duplicate issue, please upload the app in private app store or Lob store instead of sideloading. We have raised documentation update request as well for this issue. PFB details: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6072

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Do yo mean after we publish our app to teams app store, duplicate app issue will be solved? I don't understand what you meant by uploading app to private app store or Lob store instead of side loading. I didn't find any resources regarding it. Since you have raised an issue for it, so I assume it is yet to be added.

Comment: This is the doc reference for LoB apps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/working-with-line-of-business-apps   FYI we have raised doc update for sideloading app multiple times shows more than one instance for Messaging Extension

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT Thanks for the doc reference. If I directly publish my current app[with out uploading it on LOB store] to teams for review, will the users face duplicate app issue when they try to install it from teams app store?

Comment: Yes, you might face duplication issue.

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I think uploading an app to LOB store instead of sideloading is just another way to get rid of duplicate app issue. I assume it is still a bug and uploading to LOB store is not a solution. Will it be fixed in future? or do we need to continue to upload in LOB store?

Comment: There is no such plan/ETA for the fix.

Answer (score 0):

When you install an app by side loading, it actually creates different app id with existing app due to which it even considers as separate app. If you want to get rid of the duplicate issue, please upload the app in private app store or Lob store instead of sideloading.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-store/working-with-line-of-business-apps

We have raised documentation update request as well for this issue. PFB details: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/6072